# RAILS & RSpec: expecting <"similar_movies"> but rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is the .spec file:

```
describe MoviesController do
    describe 'similar_movies' do
        before :each do
            @fake_results = [double('movie1'), double('movie2')]
        end
        it 'should call the model method that searches similar movies' do
            expect(Movie).to receive(:similar_movies).with("1").
            and_return @fake_results
            get :similar_movies, :id => 1
        end
        it 'should select the similar_movies template for rendering' do
            Movie.stub(:similar_movies).and_return(@fake_results)
            expect(response).to render_template(:similar_movies)
            get :similar_movies, :id => 1
        end
        # it 'should make the similar_movies results avaliable to that template'do

        # end
    end
```

This is the controller action:

```
 # METHOD TO FIND MOVIES WITH THE SAME DIRECTOR AS A GIVEN ONE
   def similar_movies
    @similar_movies_arr = Movie.similar_movies(params[:id])
    #render 'similar_movies'
   end
```

This is the model method:

```
    def self.similar_movies(id)
    movie = Movie.find(id)
    director = movie['director']
    @similar_movies_arr = []
    @similar_movies = Movie.where(["director = ?", "#{director}"])
    @similar_movies.each do |m|
      @similar_movies_arr << m
    end
    return @similar_movies_arr
  end
```

And this The template:

```
    -@similar_movies_arr.each do |movie|
  %h1= movie.title
```

It's very simple, my first steps with RSpec, but it fails. Please, can someone help me to understand this error

```
MoviesController similar_movies should select the similar_movies template for rendering
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:similar_movies)
   expecting <"similar_movies"> but rendering with <[]>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you need to do the get before expecting to render template.

```
  get :similar_movies, :id => 1
  expect(response).to render_template(:similar_movies)
```

your test will still have problems because you don't have fake movies to search that you can access the director field.  You might want to look at factories to create some test movies.

The third comment is you might want to switch from using the Movie.stub to the new format of allow(Movie).to receive... like the expect earlier just using switching the allow for expect

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked with by just moving the 'get...' line, but will follow your other advises too.